# Migrate old JDBC program to use XA

Tags: jdbc, jboss, xa

What would I need to do if I want to migrate a program that is using old JDBC interfaces to support XA? I mean detail steps I need to do in the code.
The program is running on a single DB but the new features require to introduce a new schema and some old features need to support transactions across 2 schemas. We are using JBOSS.
What is the minimum set of steps to migrate this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate which version of JBoss you are using. I am assuming JBoss 5.

The minimal set of steps:

1. Get an XA compliant JDBC driver for your database.
2. Create a XA data source (e.g. `*-ds.xml) file to include the XA data source properties. See this [link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources) for configuration elements. There are several of them and some of them may apply or may not apply in your situation.
3. Update /conf/jbossts-properties.xml for XA Recovery module if needed.
4. You may also need to grant special privileges on the database system tables.